# ArcGIS: Get coverage of Polygon A in Polygon B

Tags: arcgis-desktop, spatial-statistics, overlapping-features, overlay, vector-layer

We have dissemination area (DA) units for a city [Polygon B], and shapefiles of all parks in the city [Polygon A].Polygon A overlaps Polygon B in some areas.

We initially wanted to calculate the percentage park cover in each of the dissemination areas but now we'd just be happy to create a feature class for each of the dissemination areas which includes a field in the attribute table indicating the total cover of park within its boundary.

We've tried pretty much all of the overlay tools listed in this webpage:
http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/commonly-used-tools/overlay-analysis.html ,but they haven't been able to give us a feature class with the same number of DA's as Polygon B, with the park data nested inside.

Is there a glaringly obvious tool we've missed?

It seems to be a pretty easy task but we've really hit a bit of a wall with it.

Here is a screenshot. Polygon A in green, Polygon B represented by the red lines.

[image]

Comment: If you tested all overlay tools you also used intersect. Was it not the outcome you wanted? Workflow should be with intersect: intersect - area calculation - summarize in the attribute table for your desired attribute - join back to you original data.

Comment: @Matte You know what? We had done that and we thought it wasn't correct BUT we then used Dissolve on the intersect feature class and now have the total coverage of park polygon for each dissemination area! Thanks for prompting us to try Intersect again :)

Comment: Ah ok, dissolve as alternative for the summarize is also a good idea. Nice that you found it. You want to write your findings as an answer?